# Function in R missing missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed - not is.na()

Tags: r

I am trying to sort these school grades in a variable but, I am running into this "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" initially I thought - "Okay this is going to be the NA values." Unfortunately I added the recommended in other posts if is.na(x) and I still get the error.

Here is my code:

```
convert.factor <- function(val){
  if(val <= 1.49){
    return("F/E")
  } else if(val >= 1.50 & val <= 2.49) {
    return("D")
  } else if(val >= 2.50 & val <= 3.49) {
    return("C")
  } else if(val >= 3.50 & val <= 4.49) {
    return("B")
  } else if (val >= 4.50 & val <= 5.00){
    return("A")
  } else if ( is.na(val)){
    return("NA")
  }
}

WaveOne$GPA <- sapply(WaveOne$V139, convert.factor)
```

Here are some discriptive statistics on the variable itself:
[image]

Comment: do you know about `cut`?

Comment: you seem to be reinventing `cut(WaveOne$V139, breaks=c(0,1.5, 2.5,3.5,4.5,5), labels=c('E/F','D','C','B','A'))`

Comment: that should handle `NA`s nicely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want to re-invent `cut` you have to use `ifelse` instead of `if`. It should be something ugly like:

```
convert.factor <- function(val){
  ifelse(val<1.5, 'E/F',
    ifelse(val<2.5, 'D',   # no need to repeat val>=1.5 now!
      ifelse(val<3.5, 'C',
        ifelse(
          ...              # you complete here     
      )
    )
  )
} # you do not need to use return()
```

Otherwise `cut` is shorter and easier to read!

```
cut_grade <- function(grade) cut(
  grade,
  breaks=c(0,1.5, 2.5,3.5,4.5,5),
  labels=c('E/F','D','C','B','A')
)
```

In all cases, you don't have to think about the `NA`s, which should propagate nicely to the factor.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this cut method! :)